# is the Authorization code in OAuth 2 is used only once for the lifetime of the client Application running server?

Tags: facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

I am reading [this blog](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/oauth2/authorization.html) on how OAuth2 works. It is an excellent source and I guess I have understood the basics of how OAuth2 works.

when reading about `Authorization grant`, that involves granting access to the Application server (my server) which exchanges the authorization code it received from authorization sever (eg facebook) through the redirect URI registered.

myserver then exchanges this authorization code for access_token and refresh token. when the access token is expired, refresh token is used to get a new access token.

**Q1)** From this flow, I see that the authorization code given by facebook is used only once from my server to get the access_token. For subsequent requests, this authorization code is not used. Is this correct ?

If the user log-in to my server after 3 days during which the access token has expired, my server will use refresh token to get a new access token and use this access token.

**Q2)** Does the refresh token expire or each time a refresh token is used to get a new access token, a new refresh token is provided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Q1)** [RFC6749, Section 4.1.2 Authorization Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2): *The client MUST NOT use the authorization code more than once.*

**Q2)** [RFC6749, Section 6 Refreshing an Access Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6): *The authorization server MAY issue a new refresh token, in which case the client MUST discard the old refresh token and replace it with the new refresh token.*